# Идентификатор rand не определен, почему?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Visual Studio ни в какую не хочет работать с функцией rand(). Пишу на C++. Выдает ошибку "Идентификатор rand не определен". В чем проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int randomDigits[3] = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        randomDigits[i] = rand();
        cout << randomDigits[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а `std::rand()` работает?

Comment: Какая версия студии?

Comment: @alexolut версия 15.3.5

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n есть же **using namespace std;**. Все равно не работает

Comment: Скопировал, запустил, компилируется без замечаний. VC++ 2015

Comment: скопируйте то, что выводиться в окне компиляции. может там есть другие полезные сообщения

Comment: @Harry у ТС судя по номеру 2017.

Comment: Насколько я помню, у VS всегда были проблемы с заголовочными файлами cstd****. Подключите <stdlib.h> - в MSDN именно это указано для rand().

Answer (score 1):

Включи заголовочный файл:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: E него есть `#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;` - это то же самое.

Comment: То же, да не то же. Как писали еще в комментариях, в VS бывают проблемы с подключением cstd*** файлов.